# Are functions not part of .obj file?

Tags: c++

**according to the book im reading it says:**
After examining a program syntax the C++ compiler creates .obj file. Next the compiler calls the linker that combines program statements inside your .obj files with some functions such as printf().

Are functions not part of .obj file? Are they not statements?
Does the linker have a connection with the terms "static linking" and "dynamic linking"?

I know that dynamic linking is resolved at runtime, but according to the book the linker is called at compile time.

Comment: I'm not clear on the question. Are you asking the difference between static and dynamic linking? Are you asking what's in the .obj after static linking?

Comment: first question is if function you created will become part of obj file. Static and Dynamic linking is just additional question.

Comment: You should edit your question to include better punctuation.  The entire first paragraph is a giant run-on sentence.

Comment: It sounds like you should probably have a conversation with a programmer rather than posting questions on this site.

Comment: some people from this site are programmers right?

Comment: Are you somehow thinking that `.obj` files should only contain "C++ objects"?

Comment: According to the book it says .obj file will contain statements in my code, but it also said the linker will combine .obj file with some functions such as printf(). Im curious why it will combine functions with .obj file, is functions will be included in .obj file?

Answer (score 1):

Functions which are defined in your `.cpp` are present in the corresponding `.obj`. Functions which are used but not defined (such as standard library functions like `printf`) aren't part of it. The linker solve the references with other `.obj` and libraries.

- static libraries are just a collection of `.obj` and the linker take the `.obj` which provides needed symbols and put them in the executable;
- dynamic libraries aren't put in the executable; the executable is marked as referencing them and they are found back when the executable starts. (At least in their main use, they may also be used for plugins and then they are searched when the process asks for them).

Comment: I see, so function that i wrote will be part of .obj file unlike functions in the library.

Comment: is dynamic library and DLL same? is DLL is dynamic linking?

Comment: DLL is for Dynamically Linked Library.

Comment: what are examples of static library and dynamic library?

Answer (score 0):

Well technically there's really no such thing as "dynamic linking" as something done by the linker. There's really only manually binding to a piece of code at run time, which really has nothing to do with the linker.

For example, under Windows there's a few ways of dealing with a dll

1. The lowest level solution is to use [LoadLibrary or AfxLoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/64tkc9y5%28v=vs.80%29) to manually access the function by name, casting them to a function pointer of the appropriate type.
2. You can use an [import lib](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67wc07b9.aspx). This allows the linker to resolve functions in other dlls at link time. So you can directly call a function in the dll (ie just by saying `Foo()` in client code). However, those functions are simply wrappers for the `LoadLibrary` method mentioned above. They load the dll if not loaded, directly access a function pointer in that library, then execute that function.